# Why does my code calling a function twice?

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int bolucu(int n){
int temp;
temp=n;
int basamak=0;
while(temp != 0){
    temp/=10;
    ++basamak;
}
int digits = 0;
int m = n;
while (m) {
    digits++;
    m /= 10;
}
digits /= 2;
int tmp = 0, lower_half = 0;
while (digits--) {
    tmp *= 10;
    tmp += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
}
while (tmp) {
    lower_half *= 10;
    lower_half += tmp % 10;
    tmp /= 10;
}
if (basamak % 2==1){
    n/=10;
}
int a;
int b;
a = n;
b=lower_half;
printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
int loopTemp;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    a=3*a+2;
    b=2*b+3;
    if(a>b){
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    if(a==b){
        printf("Congratulations you caught one!!!\n");
        return 1;
        break;
    }
}
if(a!=b){
    printf("10 tries were not enough!\n");
    return 2;
}
}
int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("\nEnter a number with at least two digits: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    bolucu(number);
    while(bolucu(number) != 1){
    printf("\nEnter a new number: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    printf("%d",bolucu(number));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

e.g:
[This is terminal screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtxh1.png)

As you can see there is a second one. First one is true but i don't want second one.
How can i get rid of the second calling?
(Also sorry for bad code writing, i'm new)
What im missing here?
And i cant use any library other than stdio.(Like math.h)

Comment: You call `bolucu(number);` three times in `main()`. Eliminate two of them?

Comment: In this code firstly ask like this"Enter a number with at least two digits:" And then loop should be like this "Enter a new number:". My friend want this way.

Comment: I'm not sure what this program is doing, but maybe you want to store the result: `int result; while ((result = bolucu(number)) != 1) { ... }`

Comment: You also have some issues in your `bolucu` function: `loopTemp` is never used and the consecutive `return 1;` and `break` statements are pointless.

Comment: Code is doing this: First user input integer. And function split this number from middle. If digits are odd numbers we eliminate middle number. Then we have 2 numbers, first one is a and second one is b. Function trying 10 times a=3*a+2 and b=2*b+3 if a=b happens function writes Congs. you caught one. If a!=b 10 times code wants new input from user. And its trying until a=b condition is met.

Comment: Thanks i used loopTemp in for loop. And i deleted break. But still i get same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because you call the `bolucu()` function both inside the `while` loop and in it's condition check. To fix this, call the function and hold it's result in a variable once, and then use that single result in both the check and your print statement. Your main function can be rewritten like so:

```c
int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("\nEnter a number with at least two digits: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    int result = bolucu(number);
    while (result != 1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a new number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        result = bolucu(number);
        printf("%d", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It has worked. By the way bolucu means "divider" in turkish sorry for turkish word.

Comment: @Cenk28 ahaha no worries, Türkçe anlıyorum :)